# jQuery - make sure text box is empty

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following project on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TXQ9U/12/

Now I would lik to write a jquery script which through which my HTML element:

```
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
```

Is checken and displays an error when nothing is filled on. Therefore i written the following jquery:

```
function validate()

var userName = //??

if (userName.length == 0)

alert("Please, enter your name");

else
    alert ("Thanks");

)
)
```

I'm only not sure what I have to fill as var username. Anybody suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [attribute equal selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) along with [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of your input by specified name:

```
var userName = $('input[name="firstname"]').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname"><br>
```

you could do this by java script by adding **"id"** to it ,

```
var userName=document.getElementById("fname")
```

or more simpler by using jquery ,

```
var userName = $('#fname').val()
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: That `getElementByName()` method you're referring to does not exist.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thank u . it would be more appropriate to use it for an array and it is `getElementsByName()` ofcourse